# PieChart in mvc4 from Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, using, pie-chart

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 project, and I need to generate a pie chart from database using Entity Framework. Now I am displaying some hard-coded values from the model, but I need to generate it from Entity Framework data.

Comment: Checkout http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/ DotNet HighCharts

Comment: Well, you just basically have to load the appropriate data from your database using Entity Framework. StackOverflow isn't a place to teach those most basic introductory tutorials - just search on Google or Bing for "Entity Framework tutorial" and start learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Report Builder 3.0 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6116